# docker load image results in repository:none and tag:none

Tags: docker-for-windows

I compiled a docker image from this git repository https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker

```
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
floydhub/dl-docker   cpu                 06cac7b0d659        5 days ago          7.75 GB
```

Then I saved it with this command `docker save 06cac7b0d659 > dl-docker.tar` When I load it on another pc however I lose both the repository and the tag.

```
<none>               <none>              06cac7b0d659        5 days ago          7.75 GB
```

Can someone tell me what has happened ? Im not sure if I saved using the image ID or the repository/tag name.